# Reading font names from font files on Windows, Linux and Mac?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using C++ and Qt and I want to find a cross-platform solution for reading font names from font files.  Looking through the Qt font classes, I can't see any solution.  The closest I could get is the below code which reads the font family, but not the full font name, so "Arno Pro Regular" just returns "Arno Pro", "Blogger Sans Bold" just returns "Blogger Sans", and so forth.

```
int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(fileName);
if (id != -1)
{
    QStringList fontFamily = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id);
    QFontDatabase::removeApplicationFont(id);
}
```

I've searched around for a solution, but can only find solutions in Java, .net and other languages, but nothing I can use in C++.

Is there any cross-platform way of reading font names from font files in C++?

Comment: What you're referring to as the "full font name" is the name of the font family and the name of one of its available styles. See [QFontDatabase::styles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#styles).

Comment: @molbdnilo Unfortunately, there's no way way to determine which style is associated with a font that has been added with QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont().  None of the other QFontDatabase functions take the font ID as a parameter, so Qt doesn't seem to offer any way to determine the full font name (family+style) from the opened font file.

Comment: For any given font family you can get a list of the available styles with [`QFontDatabase::styles`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#styles).